# how to set extended_permission using facebook-python-sdk?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

i found this code for pyFacebook ..

```
client = facebook.Facebook(api_key, secret_key)
client.auth.createToken()
client.login()
client.auth.getSession()
client.request_extended_permission("publish_stream", popup=False)
```

but i want the simliar code for facebook-python-SDK that request the extended permission without poping up the winoow ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. we no longer support the Facebook python sdk.
2. if memory serves, the Facebook python sdk required the use of JS SDK for authentication and the python sdk just pulled the cookie out.
3. all permission requests require your app/site to display a web view with our permissions dialog.
4. showing this dialog, is very simple to do via HTTP 302 redirects. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/